# Test chrome.extension.getURL() and other chrome functions of chrome with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, jasmine

I have followed this tutorial to test vanilla javascript with jasmine:
https://dev.to/aurelkurtula/unit-testing-with-vanilla-javascript-the-very-basics-7jm

However I got the point in which a function I want to test assigns a 'src' to an 'img' element.

```
setImage(){
     const img = document.createElement('img');
     img.src = chrome.extension.getURL('images/icon.png');

     return img;
}
```

And, for the test with Jasmine I did I did:

```
it('should check image creation', () => {
     const img = document.createElement('img');
     img.src = '../images/icon.png';

     expect(setImage()).toEqual(img)
})
```

I got this error after running the test:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getURL' of undefined
```

referring to the chrome.extension.

Does anybody know how I can test this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means the context the tests are run is not within the `extension` context.

The way I do unit testing is by creating a `tests.html` webpage within the extension, and for development purposes, expose a context menu `Run Tests` that launches:

```
extension://1234123412341234/tests.html
```

As always, make sure your extension is architected in a way that the context scripts/background pages/popups are abstracted.